# XSLT 2.0 Splitting current-group() by first occurence of an element

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

Using XSLT 2.0, suppose you have `current-group()` *= { A, X, B, B, X }* where *A, B,* and *X* are elements.  What is an **efficient and legible** way to split it on the first occurrence of *B* to get two sequences *S1* and *S2* such that *S1 = { A, X }* and *S2 = { B, B, X }*?  Is it possible to accomplish this using a *xsl:for-each-group* construct?

EDIT: The elements of the `current-group()` are not guaranteed to be siblings but are guaranteed to be in document order.

---

**First attempt:** Using *xsl:for-each-group* with *group-starting-with*

```xml
<xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-starting-with="B[1]">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="position() = 1">
      <!-- S1 := current-group() -->
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <!-- S2 := current-group() -->
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

This works provided there is no preceding sibling *B* to the first *B* of the current-group().
I would have thought the position predicate `[1]` would be scoped to the select clause since `current-group()[self::B][1]` returns the correct *B*.  I'm curious to know why it doesn't scope this way.

**XML**

```xml
<root>
  <A>A1</A>
  <B>B1-1</B>
  <B>B1-2</B>
  <A>A2</A>
  <B>B2-1</B>
  <B>B2-2</B>
</root>
```

**XSLT**

```xml
<xsl:template match="root">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="A">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-starting-with="B[1]">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="position() = 1">
            <S1><xsl:copy-of select="current-group()" /></S1>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <S2><xsl:copy-of select="current-group()" /></S2>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

**Result**

```xml
<root>
  <S1>
    <A>A1</A>
  </S1>
  <S2>
    <B>B1-1</B>
    <B>B1-2</B>
  </S2>
  <S1>
    <A>A2</A>
    <B>B2-1</B>
    <B>B2-2</B>
  </S1>
</root>
```

As you can see the first group is correctly split, but the second group is not.  This will work, however, if you wrap the current-group() in a parent and then pass that to the select clause, but that seems inefficient.

Comment: Saxon 10 in the commercial editions has functions `items-before` and `items-from` e.g. http://saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!functions/saxon/items-before. You could roll your own if needed but I don't have a clear understanding of your input, is there only the requirement to split the sequence on that first `B`? Is the existence of that `B` ensured? Do you need to split on further sequences of `B`s? And it is also not clear whether you want to solve that for the input where the elements are siblings or for any sequence of `A, X, B, B, X`, independent of their order/relation in the XML

Comment: @MartinHonnen thanks for the quick reply!  The existence of `B` is not ensured.  I'm not sure what you mean by "further sequences of `B`."  And in this particular case, the elements of the group always be in document order but not necessarily siblings.

Comment: `group-starting-with="B[1]"` starts a new group at any item matching the pattern `B[1]`, and this pattern matches any `B` element that is the first `B` child of its parent; it's unrelated to the position of `B` in the `select` sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `functx` library defines a functions `functx:index-of-node` (http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/functx_index-of-node.html):

```
<xsl:function name="functx:index-of-node" as="xs:integer*"
              xmlns:functx="http://www.functx.com">
  <xsl:param name="nodes" as="node()*"/>
  <xsl:param name="nodeToFind" as="node()"/>

  <xsl:sequence select="
  for $seq in (1 to count($nodes))
  return $seq[$nodes[$seq] is $nodeToFind]
 "/>

</xsl:function>
```

That would reduce your second approach to

```
<xsl:template match="root">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="A">
        <xsl:variable name="pos" select="functx:index-of-node(current-group(), (current-group()[self::B])[1])"/>
        <S1>
            <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[position() lt $pos]"/>
        </S1>
        <S2>
            <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[position() ge $pos]"/>
        </S2>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

In the "new" "XSLT 4" world of Saxon 10 PE or EE with the extension functions [`saxon:items-before`](http://saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!functions/saxon/items-before) and [`saxon:items-from`](http://saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!functions/saxon/items-from) and [syntax extension for anonymous functions](http://saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!extensions/syntax-extensions/simple-inline-functions) you could write it as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all" version="3.0">

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="A">
                <S1>
                    <xsl:apply-templates
                        select="saxon:items-before(current-group(), .{ . instance of element(B) })"/>
                </S1>
                <S2>
                    <xsl:apply-templates
                        select="saxon:items-from(current-group(), .{ . instance of element(B) })"/>
                </S2>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```